# EMR cluster fails to download bootstrap action in another bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am trying to patch an AWS EMR cluster using bootstrap actions ([as AWS suggests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-log4j-vulnerability.html)). However, the same cluster is created in two regions A and B under the same account.

Steps followed so far:

1. Create bucket (in region A)
2. Upload patch file to bucket
3. Configure the bootstrap action to run the patch file in the bucket

It works but only in the cluster in the region A. The cluster running in region B fails to start due to:

```
The bucket is in this region: eu-west-1. Please use this region to retry the request
```

The error is in the bootstrap action logs and comes from the java client that AWS uses to download and run the bootstrap action, so I cannot change it.

How to have a bootstrap action in one bucket and use it for EMR clusters in different regions?

Creating a second bucket in region B would work but I need to duplicate the patch files and configure it properly in EMR clusters. In the future there might be more regions so I would avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to share a bootstrap action across clusters in different regions. The bootstrap action needs to be hosted in a bucket in the same region as the cluster.